# Showing records from Database table to a page template SilverStripe

Tags: silverstripe

I am very new in SilverStripe thats why, facing so many problem. I want to retrieve data from table and show them in a page template.I have created a modeladmin and from there i can insert records but i cant figure out how could i retrieve those data and show them in a page template? basically my codes are bellow....

```
mysite/code/SerialsCollection.php

<?php

class SerialsCollection extends DataObject {

    private static $db = array(
        'Title' => 'Varchar',
        'Author' => 'Varchar',
        'Publisher' => 'Varchar',
        'PublicationYear' => 'Date',

    );

    private static $searchable_fields = array(
      'Title',
      'Author'
   );


   private static $field_labels = array(
      'Title' => 'Title' // renames the column to "Cost"
   );

   private static $summary_fields = array(
      'Title',
      'Author',
      'Publisher',
      'PublicationYear',
   );

    public function canView($member = null) {
        return Permission::check('CMS_ACCESS_MyAdmin', 'any', $member);
    }

    public function canEdit($member = null) {
        return Permission::check('CMS_ACCESS_MyAdmin', 'any', $member);
    }

    public function canDelete($member = null) {
        return Permission::check('CMS_ACCESS_MyAdmin', 'any', $member);
    }

    public function canCreate($member = null) {
        return Permission::check('CMS_ACCESS_MyAdmin', 'any', $member);
    }
}

and mysite/code/SerialsCollectionAdmin.php ... 
<?php

class SerialsCollectionAdmin extends ModelAdmin {

    private static $managed_models = array(
        'SerialsCollection'
    );

    private static $url_segment = 'serials-collection';

    private static $menu_title = 'Serials Collection';

    public function getList() {
        $list = parent::getList();

        return $list;
    }

now, I am able to insert new records, view all and edit particular record. But what i want to create a page template and show these records on that page. I have tried it this way....

mysite/code/SerialsCollectionPage.php

<?php
Class SerialsCollectionPage extends Page{

}
Class Serials_Collection_Page_Controller extends Page_controller{
    public function SerialsCollections() 
    { 

        return DataObject::get("SerialsCollection"); 
    }
}
themes/SLIS/templates/SerialsCollectionPage.ss

<% include Header %>
<div id="Content">
        <h1>This is SerialsCollection Page</h1>
    <% control SerialsCollection %>

        <p>Title: $Title</p>
        <p>Author: $Author</p>
        <p>Publication Year:$PublicationYear</p>

    <% end_control %>

    </div>
<% include Footer %>
```

But I got nothing only if i write something into content on the page then the contents are coming.
Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

in the **Page_Controller:**

if SerialsCollection has only one instance make sure you get that instance alone, and make sure you use a get function:

```
public function getSerials(){
    return SerialsCollection::get()->First();// for one item
    return SerialsCollection::get();//for an array (use only one of those)
}
```

the get() alone will return a collection (ArrayList) which you will have to loop

in the **Template**
if you used the First(one item):

```
$Serials.Title
```

will print the title or if you used the array:

```
<% loop $Serials %>
    $Title
<% end_loop %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Read Querying Data from http://doc.silverstripe.org/en/developer_guides/model/data_model_and_orm/ .

In your case you would get data from the dataobjects with:

`$sc = SerialsCollection::get();`

Also you should read this: http://doc.silverstripe.org/en/developer_guides/model/lists/

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i am facing the problem still now.... if i go to the admin and create a new page with Serials Collection Page type , I am not able to see the static contents of that page as you can see on themes/SLIS/templates/SerialsCollectionPage.ss section , there are still a static title <h2> This is Serials Collection Page</h2> but i can see nothing. I just see if i put dynamic content from admin text editor.   
I have created a custom home page template and its working perfectly but when i create custom page template like Serials Collection Page, its not working i dont know why..

Comment: Maybe you should add your Serials Collection Page and template source also to your question. Would help a lot. As for a quick tip did you remember to ?flush or ?flush=all when adding files.